# Codeigniter Migrations + Multiple Tables + One Migration File Per Table

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, migration

I want to begin using DBForge and migrations class thats built into CI but im not sure how to go about creating migrations for all of my tables.

My thoughts are in my installer process to have a migration file for each of the following tables: `advertisements, announcements, config, users, points`.. When the user is installing the app, it will automatically run through these migration files and create the tables.

IE: `001_advertisements, 001_announcements, 001_config, 001_users, 001_points`

**001_map_advertisements**

```
class Migration_map_advertisements extends CI_Migration {

public function up(){
    $this->dbforge->add_field(array(
        'id' => array(
            'type' => 'INT',
            'constraint' => 11,
            'unsigned' => TRUE,
            'auto_increment' => TRUE
        ),
        'youtube_id' => array(
            'type' => 'VARCHAR',
            'constraint' => '255',
        ),
        'status' => array(
            'type' => 'int',
            'constraint' => 11,
            'null' => FALSE,
            'default' => 1
        ),
        'timestamp' => array(
            'type' => 'int',
            'constraint' => 11
        ),
        'type' => array(
            'type' => 'VARCHAR',
            'default' => 'video'
        ),
        'filename' => array(
            'type' => 'VARCHAR',
            'constraint' => '255'
        ),
        'url' => array(
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'constraint' => '255'
        ),
        'description' => array(
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'constraint' => 64
        ),
        'title' => array(
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'constraint' => 64
        )
    ));
    $this->dbforge->create_table('map_advertisements', TRUE);
}

public function down()
{
    $this->dbforge->drop_table('map_advertisements');
}
```

**However if i do this and attempt to run a secured controller:**

```
class Developer extends ADMIN_Controller {
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
} #end constructor function
public function migrate($index){
    $this->load->library('migration');

    if ( !$this->migration->version($index) ){
        show_error($this->migration->error_string());
    }else{
        echo 'migrated';
    }

}
}
```

i get an error stating that there are multiple `version 1` migrations and it fails the migration process. Is there another way to go about this in CI?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can only have one migration file per version.  A migration is not table-specific, but more like "what schema changes are needed to go from version x to version x+1 of my app?"

Combine all of your existing migration files into 1, and name it something like `001_initial_schema.php`.  Then, when add a new feature, create a new schema file for that feature.  If you have a deployment cycle (like weekly SCRUM sprints), it's nice to have one of these migration files per deployment.

Comment: can you provide an example snippet as to how i can create several table migrations in one file? I have added my migration code to my answer for reference for a single table.

Comment: Combine all the `up()` and `down()` methods from the several files.  It's a simple copy/paste, but you'll need to put them in the order the tables should be created (and, conversely, the order they should be dropped in the `down()` method).

Comment: You could circumvent all this by renaming your files `001_...`, `002_...`, etc.

Comment: yeah but which is the better route to go, i am starting from scratch. I have an existing database and I'm going to create migrations for future installs of the app.

Comment: Combine all feature-related or deployment-related schema updates in the same migration class.  There's no sense in splitting it up by table.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/migration.html, the best way to "version" your migrations is using the YYYYMMDDHHMMSS format.  This should effectively overcome versioning issues as expressed.  It is also suggested that if the the filename was "201507071208_advertisements.php" that the contained migration class should be called "Migration_Advertisements".